# Missing ObservableCollection(of T)

Tags: vb.net, observablecollection

I'm doing an experiment on WPF and MVVM, and while coding the ViewModel on Vb.net I noticed this red wavy lines under my ObservableCollection(of T)s T_T

Anyway, the application is in WPF & VB.Net, under the .Net Framework 3.5 (I checked) and I have an 'Imports System.Collections.ObjectModel' on top of my class. Intellisense shows the other classes on System.Collections.ObjectModel except ObservableCollection.

Here's a [screenshot](http://i79.photobucket.com/albums/j123/Kadaj13_photos/Question.png).

So, why is ObservableCollection(of T) missing and how do I make it appear? :( Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You need to add a reference to WindowsBase. Some elements in System.Collections live in mscorlib, but the WPF specific things like ObservableCollection live in WindowsBase.dll

Confusing I know :-)

Comment: Just wanted to point out that in .Net 4, ObservableCollection's been moved to System.dll